# Haskell don't really know what to name this

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm trying to make it so that on a tuple input (n,m) and a list of tuples xs , if the first item in the tuple in xs is in (n,m) then keep it that way in the new list otherwise add the a tuple consisting of some value k from n to m as a first element and as second element it should be 0.My question is:how can i say "repeat 0" using guards ? Since clearly my code won't run since my code says "repeat = 0"

```
expand :: (Int,Int) -> Profile ->Profile
expand (n,m) [] = zip [n..m] (repeat 0)
expand (n,m) (x:xs) = zip [n..m] (repeat (|(fst (x) `elem` [n..m]) == False = 0
                                                                |otherwise = snd (x))
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to do. You can use `any`/`all`/... in a guard expression. But here the logic does not belong in a guard as far as I can see, but in another function that specifies what to add as second element.

Comment: `if ... then ... else ... ` is an expression in Haskell, evaluating to one of the branches.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you give some examples on input and expected output?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper function here that converts a number in the `[ n .. m ]` range to a 2-tuple. Here we thus try to find an element in the list `xs` that matches with the first item of that tuple, if we do not find such element, we use `0`:

```
import Data.List(find)

expand :: (Int,Int) -> Profile -> Profile
expand (n,m) xs = map go [n .. m]
    where go i | Just l <- find (\(f, _) -> f == i) xs = l
               | otherwise = (i, 0)
```

For a list, `find` was [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#find):

> ```
> find            :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
> find p          = listToMaybe . filter p
> ```

`filter` thus will make a list that contains the elements that satisfy the predicate `p`, and [**`listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe) will convert an empty list `[]` to `Nothing`, and for a non-empty list `(x:_)` it will wrap the first element `x` in a `Just` data constructor. Due to Haskell's laziness, it will thus look for the first element that satisfies the predicate.

this thus gives us:

```
Prelude Data.List> expand (2,7) [(4, 2.3), (6, 3)]
[(2,0.0),(3,0.0),(4,2.3),(5,0.0),(6,3.0),(7,0.0)]
```